# Xamarin Social post without interface prompt - ShareItemAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.social

I'm trying to post directly to facebook/twitter without prompting the user with a UIViewController using the following code:

```
// 1. Create the service
var facebook = new FacebookService {
    ClientId = "<App ID from developers.facebook.com/apps>",
    RedirectUrl = new System.Uri ("<Redirect URL from developers.facebook.com/apps>")
};

// 2. Create an item to share
var item = new Item { Text = "Xamarin.Social is the bomb.com." };
item.Links.Add (new Uri ("http://github.com/xamarin/xamarin.social"));

// 3. Present the UI on iOS
var shareController = facebook.GetShareUI (item, result => {
    // result lets you know if the user shared the item or canceled
    DismissViewController (true, null);
});
PresentViewController (shareController, true, null);
```

BUT the Xamarin.Social instructions say:

```
 As an alternative to presenting the share UI, you can share items directly using the **ShareItemAsync** method of the service.
```

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social

I can't find any examples or explicit tutorials on how to use this.  Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source of [Xamarin.Social](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social), internally [ShareItemAsync](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Social.iOS/ShareViewController.cs) is used anyways to carry out the requests. GetShareUI is just a wrapper around ShareItemAsync.

From the source of [ShareViewController](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Social.iOS/ShareViewController.cs) (which gets the UI), you can see how they are using ShareItemAsync to carry out the requests. Here's the snippet for you.

```
try {
    service.ShareItemAsync (item, account).ContinueWith (shareTask => {
        StopSharing ();  
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());
            }
```

So all you need to do is create the item, get hold of the account and call the method on the service, something like this

```
var item = new Item { Text = "Xamarin.Social is the bomb.com." };
item.Links.Add (new Uri ("http://github.com/xamarin/xamarin.social"));

var account = facebook.GetAccountsAsync().FirstOrDefault();

facebook.ShareItemAsync(item, account);
```

Comment: var account = facebook.GetAccountsAsync().FirstOrDefault();  --> throws error: arguments couldnt be inferred, specify type arguments explicitly

Comment: I gave you the full source... You could atleast try to go through that.. Replace "var account = ..." with "Task<IEnumerable<Account>> account = ..."

Comment: Thanks for the direction of where to go, @MohibSheth but there's quite a bit more one has do between var account = facebook.GetAccountsAsync().FirstOrDefault();
 and facebook.ShareItemAsync(item, account);